# override a html table td style

Tags: html, css

I am trying to overwrite a td style like this:

```
.valuator .sw-slots table, tr, td { width 100% }
```

so I did this:

```
 td.license-name-td{
  width: 100px !important;
}
```

The table took always the "global" style and overwrites, rather ignores my style. Even chrome doesn't cross the link out, it just ignores that part.

```
  td.license-name-td {
    width: 100px !important
  } 

.valuator .sw-slots table, tr, td {
    width: 100%;
 }
```

(Chrome computed css output)

Is there a special way to overwrite the td tag afterwards?

```css
.valuator .sw-slots table, tr, td {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  text-align: right;
  color: #3c3c3c;
}

table.license-table td.license-name-td {
  text-align: left !important;
  word-break: break-word;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px !important;
}

table.license-table td.license-td {
  text-align: left !important;
  margin-left: 3px;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<table class="t3lsg license-table" style="font-size: 12px;">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th style="text-align: left;">Software</th>
    <th style="text-align: left;">Version</th>
    <th style="text-align: left;">Source</th>
    <th style="text-align: left;">License</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      <div style="height: 1px; background-color: lightgrey; margin: 3px 0 3px 0;">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="license-name-td">Fleck</td>
    <td class="license-td">0.9.6.19</td>
    <td class="license-td">https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck</td>
    <td class="license-td">MIT License</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      <div style="height: 1px; background-color: lightgrey; margin: 3px 0 3px 0;">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
        <tr>
    <td class="license-name-td">HTML Agility Pack</td>
    <td class="license-td">HAP 1.4.6</td>
    <td class="license-td">http://code.google.com/p/heartcode-canvasloader/</td>
    <td class="license-td">Microsoft Public License </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      <div style="height: 1px; background-color: lightgrey; margin: 3px 0 3px 0;">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="license-name-td">jQuery</td>
    <td class="license-td">1.10.2002</td>
    <td class="license-td">http://jquery.com</td>
    <td class="license-td">MIT License</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      <div style="height: 1px; background-color: lightgrey; margin: 3px 0 3px 0;">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="license-name-td">jQuery Knob</td>
    <td class="license-td">11.2.8</td>
    <td class="license-td">http://anthonyterrien.com/knob</td>
    <td class="license-td">MIT License</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

EDIT: I changed one mistake, that i forgot to change one inline style to a class, now this is the new result.

Comment: Can you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: please give us more details this info is too limited

Comment: at least the relevant html

Comment: Please provide a test case that is complete enough to reproduce the problem *in the question itself*. There is a snippet button in the editor for Stackoverflow that allows you to provide a live example. There is no need to divert people to a third party site like JSFiddle. I can't see a problem with the code, and am assuming it lies in the HTML.

Comment: i will provide a snippet, sorry!

Comment: Delete the trs you are using as dividers, and the ones without license-name-td cells, and you will understand. I would recommend you set your widths in colgroups, but from your markup it seems you are expecting cells within a column to be able to take different widths. This is not how tables work (just try it in excel ;)).

Comment: this isn´t the solution, it would not explain the behaviour of toggling the width of the .valuator .sw-slots table, tr, td class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, in your example code, I added the two enclosing `div`'s (`.valuator`, `.sw-slots`) so that the first CSS rule applies to the table.

After that, you need to make sure that the widths of the table cell are set to a default of `auto` except for `td.license-name-td` which had a 100px width.

You need to reset the `td` for the separator `td[colspan="4"]` to `width: auto` and then the same for `td.license-td`.

I think this is what you need.  Just be on the look out for other CSS rules that might be in hour style sheets that might override these.

```css
.valuator .sw-slots table, tr, td {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  text-align: right;
  color: #3c3c3c;
}
td[colspan="4"] {
  width: auto;
}
td.license-name-td {
  text-align: left;
  word-break: break-word;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
td.license-td {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 3px;
  word-break: break-word;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="valuator">
  <div class="sw-slots">
    <table class="t3lsg" style="font-size: 12px;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th style="text-align: left;">Software</th>
          <th style="text-align: left;">Version</th>
          <th style="text-align: left;">Source</th>
          <th style="text-align: left;">License</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">
            <div style="height: 1px; background-color: lightgrey; margin: 3px 0 3px 0;">
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="license-name-td">Fleck</td>
          <td class="license-td">0.9.6.19</td>
          <td class="license-td">https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck</td>
          <td class="license-td">MIT License</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">
            <div style="height: 1px; background-color: lightgrey; margin: 3px 0 3px 0;">
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="license-name-td">HTML Agility Pack</td>
          <td class="license-td">HAP 1.4.6</td>
          <td class="license-td">http://code.google.com/p/heartcode-canvasloader/</td>
          <td class="license-td">Microsoft Public License</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">
            <div style="height: 1px; background-color: lightgrey; margin: 3px 0 3px 0;">
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="license-name-td">jQuery</td>
          <td class="license-td">1.10.2002</td>
          <td class="license-td">http://jquery.com</td>
          <td class="license-td">MIT License</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">
            <div style="height: 1px; background-color: lightgrey; margin: 3px 0 3px 0;">
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="license-name-td">jQuery Knob</td>
          <td class="license-td">11.2.8</td>
          <td class="license-td">http://anthonyterrien.com/knob</td>
          <td class="license-td">MIT License</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the selector for the table rule was causing some confusion and you figured that out by adding another class name to the table.  You should be all set now.

Comment: What if i dont need the .valuator .sw-slots table, tr, td { /* style */ } class? I just dont want that class to apply to my table?

Comment: The CSS rule with the selector `.valuator .sw-slots table` sets properties that are needed for your table layout to work as you intended.  You can do this in many ways, including defining a new class like `.license-table`.  No matter how you approach this, try to keep the CSS stylesheet as concise as possible and organized for easier maintenance in the future.

Answer (score 1):

i've added a class name to my table and changed the class names to:

```
table.license-table td.license-td{
    text-align: left !important;
    margin-left:3px;
    word-break: break-word;
    width: 100px !important;
}

table.license-table td.license-name-td{
  text-align: left !important;
  word-break: break-word;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px !important;
}
```

this solves my problem.

Comment: Your table already had a class name, `.t3lsg`, so no real need to define another class name.  Also, the `!important` are not needed.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that the `width: 100%` also applies to the table. And because a all cells in a row must count up to the width of the table, it will not work to just restrict the width of the cell, you also must address the table, or the other cells in the row.

I do not know what your HTML looks like, but if the cell is the only one in the row, you could add a class to the table instead of the cell and set the width of the table to `100px` in the same way as you did for the cell, you do not have to restrict the width of the cell than, as that will be automatically.

Comment: You're assuming there is only one cell in the row.

Comment: If there is more than one cell in a row, that shouldn't be a problem. The `.license-name-td` will be 100px, and the other(s) will take the remaining space.

Comment: Not if the others are set to 100%.